# Random number generator, unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python

The goal of my code below is to take 10 number from random. Then print the most data that often appears (mode/modus).

Here's what i've tried

```
import random
import statistics
from time import sleep

i=0
a=0

var1=input ("min random : ")
var2=input ("max random : ")
bb=int(var1)
ba=int(var2)
data = [[]for z in range(10)]
while i<10:
    rundum=random.randint(bb,ba)
    print(rundum)
    data[a].append(rundum)
    sleep(0.2)
    i=i+1
    a=a+1
tuple(data)
statistics.mode(data)
print(data)
```

and here's the result

```
min random : 1
max random : 10
2
5
9
1
10
7
1
6
9
9
[[2], [5], [9], [1], [10], [7], [1], [6], [9], [9]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ez\Documents\belajar random.py", line 20, in <module>
    statistics.mode(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\statistics.py", line 501, in mode
    table = _counts(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\statistics.py", line 252, in _counts
    table = collections.Counter(iter(data)).most_common()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 568, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 655, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

I don't know how to fix this problem
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `statistics`?

Comment: @KlausD. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

Comment: `data = random.choices(range(bb, ba), k=10)` may be a simpler solution for generating your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can use this:*

```
import random
import statistics
from time import sleep

bb = int(input("min random : "))
ba = int(input("max random : "))

data = []
for i in range(10):
    r = random.randint(bb, ba)
    data.append(r)
    sleep(0.2)

mode = statistics.mode(data)
print(data)
print("Mode: ", mode)
```

*Sample Result:*

```
[9, 7, 8, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 10, 6]
Mode:  8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and to declare an empty list assign `data = []` and whenever you need to add a data to the list you can use ***insert*** or ***append*** methods.

```
import random
import statistics
from time import sleep

i=0
a=0

var1=input ("min random : ")
var2=input ("max random : ")
bb=int(var1)
ba=int(var2)
data = []
while i<10:
    rundum=random.randint(bb,ba)
    print(rundum)
    data.append(rundum)
    sleep(0.2)
    i=i+1
    a=a+1

print("Mode of given data set is {}".format(statistics.mode(data)))
```

PS : Select the min and max range small otherwise you will end up with ,

```
StatisticsError: no unique mode ,found x equally common values
```

were x denotes equal number of random numbers appeared

I suggest increase the number of random numbers if possible.

**OR**

Rise an exception so that you get an appropriate output like **No unique mode in the given list**.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declare `data` like that? It should be just `data = []` and then in the `for` loop, you just need to append to data:

```
i=0
a=0
import random
from time import sleep
import statistics
var1=input ("min random : ")
var2=input ("max random : ")
bb=int(var1)
ba=int(var2)
data = []
while i<10:
    rundum=random.randint(bb,ba)
    print(rundum)
    data.append(rundum)
    sleep(0.2)
    i=i+1
    a=a+1

data = tuple(data)
print(data)
print(statistics.mode(data))
print(data)
```

Result:

```
(10, 7, 6, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 6, 5)
5
```

Or you could shorten your code:

```
import random
from time import sleep
import statistics

min_num = input("min random : ")
max_num = input ("max random : ")

for i in range(10):
    data.append(random.randint(min_num, max_num))
    sleep(0.2)

result = statistics.mode(data)
print(data)
print("Result: ", result)
#[10, 7, 6, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 6, 5]
#5
```

Comment: the reason i declare the data like that is because i only following code from the other.. turns out, it is the pproblem. Thanks for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. Each time through the for loop, it will generate a new random number.

```
from random import randint
from statistics import mode

var1 = int(input("min random : "))
var2 = int(input("max random : "))
rand_list = []

for i in range(10):
    rand_list.append(randint(var1, var2))

print(rand_list)
print(f"Most common number is {mode(rand_list)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've created a list of lists ([[2], [5], [9], [1], [10], [7], [1], [6], [9], [9]]), rather than a list. Calling mode on a list of lists will not produce the result you want.

Also, you are not using pythonic constructs. You don't need to preallocate an array and you should iterate over a range rather than incrementing variables in a while loop.

```
import random
from time import sleep
import statistics

var1=input ("min random : ")
var2=input ("max random : ")
bb=int(var1)
ba=int(var2)

data = []
for _ in range(10):
    rundum = random.randint(bb,ba)
    data.append(rundum)
    sleep(0.2)
print(statistics.mode(data))
print(data)
```